# Why is make_friedman1 used?

Tags: machine-learning

I have started to learn ML, and am confused with make_friedman1. It highly improved my accuracy, and increased the data size. But the data isn't the same, it's changed after using this function. What does friedman! actually do?

Comment: Why dont you accept answers?

Answer (score 5):

If make_friedman1 asked here is the one in sklearn.datasets then it is the function which generates the “Friedman #1” regression problem. Here inputs are 10 independent variables uniformly distributed on the interval [0,1], only 5 out of these 10 are actually used. Outputs are created according to the formula::

```
y = 10 sin(π x1 x2) + 20 (x3 - 0.5)^2 + 10 x4 + 5 x5 + e
```

where e is N(0,sd)

Quoting from the Friedman's original paper, Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines ::

> A new method is presented for flexible regression modeling of high
>   dimensional data. The model takes the form of an expansion in product
>   spline basis functions, where the number of basis functions as well as
>   the parameters associated with each one (product degree and knot
>   locations) are automatically determined by the data. This procedure is
>   motivated by the recursive partitioning approach to regression and
>   shares its attractive properties. Unlike recursive partitioning,
>   however, this method produces continuous models with continuous
>   derivatives. It has more power and flexibility to model relationships
>   that are nearly additive or involve interactions in at most a few
>   variables

A spline is adding many polynomial curves end-to-end to make a new smooth curve.